# When would you use a return statement in a Javascript closure?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

Consider this first Javascript snippet, which only uses var and this to declare scope:

```
var Bro = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.storyName = "story"; // public
    var storyType = "cool"; // private

    // private function
    var composeStory  = function() {
        return storyType + ' ' + self.storyName;
    };

    // privileged function
    this.tellStory = function() {
        console.log(composeStory() + ' bro!');
    };
};
```

Compared to this, which uses a return statement, and modifies the scope somewhat:

```
var Bro = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.storyName = "story"; // private?
    var storyType = "cool"; // private

    // private function
    var composeStory = function() {
        return storyType + ' ' + self.storyName;
    };

    // privileged variables/functions
    return {
        storyName: this.storyName,
        tellStory: function() {
            console.log(composeStory() + ' bro!');
        }
    };
}
```

My question then is:

1. When would you use the second method over the first, or is this just a stylistic thing?
2. Why is `this.storyName` in the second example private, even though I set it on `this`?
3. I had to declare `var self = this;` in order to get access to the `this` scope inside both private functions. How do Javascript frameworks make the `this` object accessible inside their functions?
4. In the second example, the `storyName` property in the return statement could access the `this`  scope properly. Why can it do that, when the private function could not?

Comment: Crackford's "[JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742)" will these and all other your questions on JavaScript internal workings. It's a must-have book for a JavaScript developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as "private" and "public" in Javascript. What you are seeing is the difference between properties on an object and closure captured variables. Closure capture variables can be used to hide state but they are hiding it on a different object attached to the functions created in the closure scope, not on the object being returned, as in other languages. With that in mind I will answer your questions,

1) I wouldn't user either form but they are stylistically similar, both are using closure capture. Note, however, the first uses the constructor pattern and the second uses a factory pattern. The first will only work if you use the new keyword prior to calling Bro the second will ignore the object created by new in favor of the object created by the object literal, but you can call it safely without prefixing it with new.

2) storyName is not private, it is set on a different object. When a function is called prefixed by new a fresh object is created and passed in as the "this" parameter. This is the object you are setting by "this.storyName". This object is then discarded in favor of the object you create in the literal. You don't see storyName because it wasn't set on the object returned.

3) You can capture this in a closure variable like self or use bind on the function to bind this to the original this. I prefer closure capture myself.

4) The this is still in scope because you are executing in the constructor function.

Comment: Which form would you recommend using?

Comment: Neither. I would recommend using a traditional JavaScript constructor pattern.

Comment: Can you explain why? And how it has benefits over the first version I gave?

Comment: It avoids creating a closure for the functions in the constructor. I would assign them to the prototype of Bro. Constructing an object using the above code is probably about 3 times more expensive than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer on the third question. They use `call` and `apply` methods available for all functions which take first argument as the context in which a function meant to be executed.

```
this.message = "hello ";
var function(argument) {
    console.log(this.message + argument);
}
function.call(this, "world!");
function.apply(this, ["world!"]);
```

For a more concise example [see jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L608).

Answer (score 0):

Question 4:  In JS, `this` has function scope, not block scope.

So in the second example, in the function `composeStory`, `this` has the scope of the function `composeStory`, not the scope of the object instance of `Bro`.  Hence you had to save off `this` as `self`, because the meaning of `this` changed.

(In fact, in the function `composeStory`, `this` will normally be `window`, or in strict mode `undefined`.  If you insert

```
alert(this === window);
```

in the `composeStory` function, it will alert "true".  If you insert

```
"use strict"; 
alert(typeof this === "undefined");
```

it will again alert "true". See further [here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/).)

In the return statement of the second example, `this` is not inside a function.  So `this` still refers to the containing function, namely the instance of `Bro` that's being created.